# UITableView as a grid in landscape and list in portrait

Tags: iphone, uitableview, grid

I have to create a view where in I have a list of items in a page control in portrait mode. However when I rotate to landscape mode, rather than having list of items, I generate a grid of items.

Any idea how can I proceed on this

Answer (score 0):

maybe [AGGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) could help.

Set the ItemWidth in the portrait mode to "superview.frame.size.width" and in landscape mode to your specific width